Exclude the last character when printing in a for loop
I am using linux and trying to code a loop which can take in variables and concatenates them into an equation. But how do I remove it for the last loop.
printf "(%s + %s) x ", $1, $2

I want to print (1 + 1) x (2 + 2) x (3 + 3), but instead I get (1 + 1) x (2 + 2) x (3 + 3) x
What should I do to exclude this last "x"?

Is this a shell script or something else?

Hi. Sooo write an if? "If last loop; then don't print x"? printf "(%s + %s) x ", $1, $2 would print , in the output, but it is no shown in your. Are you sure you are on linux? What shell or program are you writing your program for? Bash? Zsh? Ash? Dash? Fish? How are you executing the program? What other parts of the program are there? Is there a while or for loop? Also, if this is a shell or bash script, check your scripts with shellcheck.

It is NOT a shell script as what you show is incorrect syntax for what you're trying to do with  printf in shell. What is it really - awk? [edit] your question to show a [mcve] we can copy/paste to test with.

If you are actually reading values from a file with awk -- you are likely better off formatting the output in awk too.

for loop? Where? I do not see any for in your code

may be you want printf '(%s + %s) x ' 1 1 2 2 3 3 | sed 's/x $/\n/'

Rather than exclude the last x, consider excluding the first x from something like x (1 + 1) x (2 + 2) x (3 + 3). It's trivial to detect the first iteration of a loop.

This is probably what you're trying to do:
$ awk '{printf "%s(%s + %s)", sep, $1, $2; sep=" x "} END{print ""}' file
(1 + 1) x (2 + 2) x (3 + 3)

That was run against an input file created by:
$ printf '%d %d\n' 1 1 2 2 3 3
1 1
2 2
3 3

$ printf '%d %d\n' 1 1 2 2 3 3 > file


You can join lines with x:
printf "(%s + %s) \n" "$@" | paste -sd x

